# Is it possible to partially virtualize the physical address space?

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-machine, fpga, peripherals

I'm currently working on systems that include FPGAs. We've various [IP cores](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/IP-core-intellectual-property-core) that support the [AXI-Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_eXtensible_Interface). To communicate with the IP cores of PL *(programable logic)*, we need to map them onto the address space of the PS *(processing system)*. For example, for the widely used [Zynq PS](https://www.xilinx.com/products/silicon-devices/soc/zynq-7000.html) the address space is as follows *[(UG585 - Section 4.1: Address Map)](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug585-Zynq-7000-TRM.pdf)*

- **0x0000_0000 to 0x7FFF_FFFF:** Mapped to the physical memory. Either external DDR or on-chip memory
- **0x8000_0000 to 0xBFFF_FFFF**: Mapped to the PL explained above
- **0xE000_0000 to 0xFFFF_FFFF:** Various other devices on the chip

As you can see, only the first 1GB of the address space is reserved to the physical memory, and the rest is occupied by the devices either in PL or PS. So, if possible, the virtualization range can be applied only for the first 1GB to allow faster access to devices on the chip by skipping the MMU.

I know that by doing such a modification we allow any kind of process to access the physical devices of the system without any control of its privileges. So, the questions are

- Is it possible to partially virtualize the physical address space?
- If it is possible, would it be rational to do it?

Comment: Is that a question about Linux (or Unix) beside the tag?

Comment: @A.B I intentionally didn't use the name of Linux in the question in order to make it more general. But, in reality, we use embedded Linux in our system.

Comment: That seems to be a question about the capabilities of the Zynq-7000 MMU. So I'd start reading the chip documentation for the MMU and find out. On a different SoC it may be different. The other part of the question is "what's more important for your user case, raw speed, or security?" and "how much is the difference in speed in the first place under real conditions?".

Comment: @dirkt Thanks for the suggestions. Is it possible to do it in Linux?